# Pandas Removing Text Before and After Certain Characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am not sure I have a great title, so if anyone has a suggestion, I am up for it.

Let's say I have the following scenario:

Searching for "where"

Input:

```
<Dave likes cake.> <Dave goes to school.> <Where is dave today, after school?/><I do not know where dave is>
<Cindy reads a book><Where is my shoe asked cindy.><Cindy likes bacon.><Cindy goes to the park.><where did cindy go?>
<Sally drinks wine.><The lake is where I am from commented Sally><Cindy watches day time television while watching the kids.><Cindy makes great sandwiches><where is the sandwich cindy made?>
```

Desired Output:

```
<Where is dave today, after school?/><I do not know where dave is>
<Where is my shoe asked cindy.><where did cindy go?>
<The lake is where I am from commented Sally><where is the sandwich cindy made?>
```

I want to keep everything starting at the first character within another set of characters that contain the phrase I am searching for.

I also want to remove everything before the first character that contained the phrase I am looking for as well as remove everything after the last character that contained the phrase.

Any suggestions? I am unsure how to approach this, but I am thinking about using some sort of regular expression with look aheads/behinds maybe?

**Edit #1:** Context added to what I am doing

This relates to pandas because I had stored an XML file as text inside of a pandas data frame. The XML file was an SSIS package that I needed to search for specific words and phrases.

I did a join to concatenate all of the xml into 1 single line.

**Edit #2:** More Context

I had a problem with multi line SQL statements in the XML data I was looking at, that was the reason I used `' '.join` everything to 1 line.

I need to not only find where in the XML, but return all of the SQL statement if what I am looking for is part of a multi line SQL statement.

**Edit #3:**

This solution (provided from another user below) solves the problem, but it only returns the first instance. I'll remark the answer as solved if someone has a solution that returns all instances.

Solution that works but only returns the first instance:

```
df.text.str.extract(r'(?i)(<[^<]*?where[^>]*?>)')

                                               0
0          <Where is dave today, after school?/>
1                <Where is my shoe asked cindy.>
2  <The lake is where I am from commented Sally>
```

**Edit #4:** All matches returned

The user who provided my solution mentioned using `findall` instead of `extract` to return all of the lines.

This is now 100% solved.

Comment: Curious how this relates to pandas?

Comment: I edited my post to add context

Comment: Instead of joining them into a single line, why don't you just store each line in a column of a dataframe and then leverage `df['My Lines'].str.contains('where')`

Comment: Edited my post to add more context, does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str.extract`:

```
df.text.str.extract(r'(?i)(<[^<]*?where[^>]*?>)')

                                               0
0          <Where is dave today, after school?/>
1                <Where is my shoe asked cindy.>
2  <The lake is where I am from commented Sally>
```

Regex explanation:

```
(?i)                        # Case insensitive matching
(                           # Start of matching group
  <                         # matches the < character
  [^<]                      # matches anything that's *not* <
  *?                        # matches zero-unlimited times
  where                     # matches the substring where
  [^>]                      # matches anything that's *not* >
  *?                        # matches zero-unlimited times
  >                         # matches >
)                           # end of matching group
```

Comment: I created this dataframe to test: df2 = pd.DataFrame(['<Dave likes cake.> <Dave goes to school.> <Where is dave today, after school?/>'], columns=['A'])  and then I typed this: df2.A.str.extract(r'(?i)(<[^<]*?where[^>]^?>)')  The error message that got returned was re.error: nothing to repeat at position 22

Comment: When I use that dataframe, I get `<Where is dave today, after school?/>`

Comment: Okay, continuing to test.

Comment: @LunchBox you copied the regex incorrectly.  Replace the `^?` at the end, with `*?`

Comment: df.text should say df2.A  no? the ".text" is the column name?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, check my comment above, here is the command for you to paste: `df2.A.str.extract(r'(?i)(<[^<]*?where[^>]*?>)')`

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, but just because I am curious, what if the same search criteria appears multiple times?

Comment: This would only find the first occurence.  Use `findall` to find all occurrences

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

A solution might be the following:

```
import re

a ='<Dave likes cake.> <Dave goes to school.> <Where is dave today, after school?/>'
b ='<Cindy reads a book><Where is my shoe asked cindy.><Cindy likes bacon.><Cindy goes to the park.>'
def find_where(str):
    mylist =str.split('<')
    r = re.compile(".*[W,w]here")
    newlist = list(filter(r.match, mylist)) # Read Note
    finallist = ['<'+x for x in newlist]
    return finallist[0]
```

If you then apply the function to one of your strings:

```
new_a = find_where(a)
```

and print your result, you obtain your output :

```
'<Where is dave today, after school?/>'
```

Assumming that the strings you posted are elements of a column of a dataframe (as your title suggests) you can proceed as such, to apply on your dataframe :

```
df.mycolumn = df.mycolumn.apply(find_where)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, experimenting with this now. Will update once finish experimenting.

Comment: I decided to use the other answer because it is much simpler. Thank you for trying, I upvoted your post.